# What's your favorite type of beer to brew... and why?

Tags: beer, beer-styles

Many people have drastically different taste in beers. I can only imagine that carries over to the types of beer people love to brew. What's your favorite beer to brew yourself, and why?

Comment: This should be a community wiki; there's no right answer

Comment: How do we turn it into community wiki?

Comment: Edit your question and click the "Community wiki" checkbox

Comment: I don't see that checkbox anywhere. I guess I don't have permissions to create community wiki posts. If someone else does... feel free

Answer (score 3):

I like brewing lawnmower ales, with recycled yeast (sometimes more than one strain) and leftover hops.  Just because it's always a cheap brew day that gives me beer everybody (including the AB drinkers) likes.  And it always has a different off-flavor, mint, citrus, etc.

Comment: I like your style!

Answer (score 1):

I started brewing because I had a hard time finding good commercial examples of the styles I like best: English/Irish/Scottish session beers. Milds, English Browns, Irish Reds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the more full-flavored beers.  The two that worked out best for me were an Irish Red ale and and Oatmeal Stout.